# swift: Writing to a file

Tags: ios, swift, writetofile

Another swift question today.  I'm trying to publish a users name and score to a textfile to compile a highscore list.  I am using the writeToFile() function and am getting no errors, in my breakpoints the line is being reached and executed OK but I still see no changed reflected in my score.txt file.  I should mention score.txt is included in the build path for the project...not sure if that changes anything, just thought I should mention it.  Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class victoryViewController : UIViewController
{
//  Define outputs
@IBOutlet weak var submitscorebtn: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var scorename: UITextField!

//  Define a string to hold the score value
var score = String()



//
//  Begin functions
//

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    submitscorebtn.addTarget(self, action: "submitScore:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    print(score)

}

//Submit score to DB
func submitScore(sender: UIButton! )
{
    var text: String = scorename.text!
    text += ","
    text += score

    print(text)

    if let dir : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("scores.txt");

        //writing
        do {
            try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        }
        catch {print("Error writing score.")}

    }
}



}
```

Comment: How do you check the new file contents?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I have a similar read function in another view controller, so I could use that to verify there is data in the file.  Is this necessary for writing, though?

Comment: No—but you say that you are experiencing an error. I'd like to know what you are doing to detect the error to understand the problem fully. Your code looks fine, so maybe the problem is in checking for the file change...

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Well as of now there is no error being thrown, I just put a print statement inside the do{} block.  As for checking for new contents, I have the project directory open in my Finder and check for a new line being written.

Comment: @colinmcp I just created a project based on your codes and you can build it for your device directly. Please note the line 46 and 47 in ViewController.swift. On device, you will get a <b>error saving score.</b> in console output without ``file://``.  You can get the project here: https://db.tt/jst0MnNJ

Comment: @colinmcp if you uncomment line 46 and comment line 47. The error will be gone.

Comment: @Allen Thanks Allen, I tried your solution and the error is indeed gone.  But the problem still remains that there is nothing being written to scores.txt!

Comment: @colinmcp Thanks for your test. At least, it proves my answer is not a totally garbage. How did you check your score.txt? I tested it on my side and it did have a file updated. Give me some minutes and I can record how I did and put it on dropbox for your references.

Comment: @Allen I check score.txt by opening it in 'Quick Look' in my finder after the button is pressed in simulator.  Thanks for all your help on this, sorry about your answer getting downvoted

Comment: @colinmcp That's all right. Is there any possibility that you went to a wrong path to check score.txt? I just recorded how I did and uploaded a video here: https://db.tt/Vd5zxZKQ You will see contents of score.txt going from "ABCD" to "1234" in the video.

Comment: @colinmcp By the way, I can't but delete my answer. People just keep downvote it :(

Comment: @Allen Thank you SO much for that video!!!!  I followed your steps and was able to find the correct file with my data in it already.  Thanks again for taking the time to send me videos and files, I really appreciate it!!  I would give you accepted answer if I could.

Comment: @colinmcp You are welcome. I'm happy I do help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are looking at the proper file.

The file that you look at in Xcode is on your Mac, in your project directory. It is **not** the same file that the simulator or the iOS device writes to.

Finding the right file from Xcode is a bit complicated: Open the "Devices" view, select the device, select your app, open the cogwheel popup and select "Download Container..." and save it locally. Then you can inspect the contents of the Documents directory in the downloaded container and check the files contents with Xcode.